# Delay & Missing Picture issue after taking photo from camera

Tags: android, camera, imageview, uri

i am facing an issue of taking picture from android camera and then showing it to next activity. process works fine but out of 10 pictures 1 picture is missed.

steps: activity a  where i invoke camera and take picture then i pass to activity b of its URI to display in image view , repeating this cycle 10 times 1-2 times picture got missed and delay is observed of 2 sec when picture is taken and displayed into image view on next screen in the form of blank screen.

kindly check the code and guide me what mistake am i doing here?

**Activity A**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){

        String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,  // The columns we want
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};
        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "="  + // Select only mini's
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

        String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";

       //At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning ALL images, and just taking the latest one. There is a better way to narrow this down I think with a WHERE clause which is currently the selection variable
       Cursor myCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, sort);

       long imageId = 0l;
       long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
       String thumbnailPath = "";

       try{
        myCursor.moveToFirst();
       imageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
       thumbnailImageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
       thumbnailPath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
       }
       finally{myCursor.close();}

        //Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image

        String[] largeFileProjection = {
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
        };

        String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
        myCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
       String largeImagePath = "";

       try{
        myCursor.moveToFirst();

       //This will actually give you the file path location of the image.
       largeImagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
       }
       finally{myCursor.close();}
        // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They give you a handle to the actual images
        Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageId));
        Uri uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

        Intent next= new Intent(this,AddListing.class);

        next.putExtra("imageUriThumb", uriThumbnailImage.toString());
        next.putExtra("imageUriFull", uriLargeImage.toString());

        startActivity(next);

   }

   }
```

**Activity B**

```
String uri = bundle.getString("imageUriThumb");
            Uri myThumbUri = Uri.parse(uri);

            try {
                tempBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),myThumbUri);
                imgThumbnail.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                tempBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bao);

                byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                imageBytesString = Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: on which device you are testing ?

Comment: ASIAK there are some issue with Samsung Galaxy OS when you are using Native Application for capturing Image and it will not return the URI to the captured Image. Can you search the same issue more on Internet.

Comment: i have searched this issue on internet already actually these phones dont get images using intent.get("data") and that's why i used that technique. i have tried this using Samsung ace phone and same problem is there. i guess whole samsung is not good :( rest of phones like htc works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up this problem with following points:

i have searched this issue on internet already actually these phones dont get images using intent.get("data") and that's why i used above mentioned technique. i have tried this using Samsung ace phone , Samsung Galaxy and same problem is there. i guess whole Samsung dont work perfectly and delayed response is there when you have requirement of taking pictures again and again :( rest of phones like htc works perfect.